# Ubuntu sound adjusting issue

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, volume-control

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and just would like to adjust audio level simply. The problem is that if the setting is at %17 or under, it is muted fully. If higher, it makes sound at %100 level. I ought to able to adjust middle level or higher than middle but less than highest etc. I can adjust gradually the level **with system's audio setting by not using pavucontrol or additional extra application**

Comment: you can try to change volume parameter with `alsamixer`

Answer (score 0):

In this file

```
/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common
```

I added in

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

just before this block

```
[Element PCM]
switch = mute
volume = merge
override-map.1 = all
override-map.2 = all-left,all-right
```

`nano` can be used to edit the file with `sudo -s` permissions.

You need to reboot the machine to see the change.